# PDE with Variable Coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$xu_x-2yu_y+u=e^x$

According to the book, we must first solve for $dy/dx=b/a$ which in this case is $dy/dx=-2y/x$

$\frac{-1}{2y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dy$

$\frac{-1}{2}lny=lnx+d$

I am not sure where to go from here.

Edit: I am trying to solve for the general solution $u(x,y)$

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first rewrite the pde as
\begin{align}
u_x - \frac{2y}{x}u_y+\frac{u}{x} = \frac{e^x}{x}. \ \ \ (*)
\end{align}
Using the method of characteristic curves, we could express the pde as an ode in the $x$-variable of the form
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} u(x, y(x))+\frac{u}{x} = u_x + y'(x)u_y+\frac{u}{x}  = \frac{e^x}{x} \ \ (**)
\end{align}
where $y' = -2y/x$. Then, multiplying $(**)$ by $x$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(x u(x, y(x)) \right) = e^x \ \ (***)
\end{align}
Integrate $(***)$ with respect to $x$ give us
\begin{align}
xu(x, y(x)) - x_0 u(x_0, y_0)=\int^x_{x_0} \frac{d}{dz}\left( z u(z, y(z))\right)\ dz 
= \int^x_{x_0} e^z\ dz = e^x-e^{x_0}.
\end{align}
Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
u(x, y(x)) = \frac{x_0}{x} u(x_0, y_0)+ \frac{e^x-e^{x_0}}{x}. \ \ (\text{IV})
\end{align}
Here is where the magic happens. We will prescribe a not so obvious condition on $u$, namely, on the set $\{(1, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ we will have $u(1, y) = f(y)$ for some sufficiently nice function $f$. Then returning to the problem, we will first solve $y' = -2y/x$ with initial condition $y(1) = y_0$ to get
\begin{align}
y = \frac{y_0}{x^2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2y = y_0  \ \ (\text{V})
\end{align}
Plugging (V) into (IV) yields
\begin{align}
u(x, y) = \frac{1}{x} u(1, x^2y)+ \frac{e^x-e}{x} = \frac{f(x^2y)}{x}+\frac{e^x-e}{x}.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, quick question, going from line 2 to 3, wouldn't multiplying by x yield: $xy'u+u=e^x$

Comment: Just take the derivative of line 3 to get line 2.

Comment: Could you show some work for how you used integrating factor? I'm having some difficulty seeing how it was used

Comment: Observe $\frac{d}{dx}(x u(x, y(x))) = \frac{d}{dx}(x) u(x, y(x)) + x \frac{d}{dx} u(x, y(x)) = e^x$